# Parse HTML into Clean XML

Tags: html, xml, powershell

I have a file that is brought in as a ".EXCEL" file (fake excel, but that's beyond our control). It's actually HTML, but I'm having a hard time converting it to XML.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<table class="c41">
    <tr class="c5">
        <td valign="top" class="c6"><p class="c7"><span class="c8">Cash Activity </span> 
        </p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c9"><p class="c10"><br/><span class="c2">FRIDAY&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><br/><span class="c2"> </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c5">
        <td valign="top" class="c6"><p class="c11"><br/></p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c9"><p class="c10"><br/><span class="c2">05-JAN-18</span><br/><span class="c2"> </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c12">
        <td valign="top" class="c13"><p class="c7"><span class="c14">Prior Day Available Balance</span></p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c15"><p class="c10"><span class="c16">6,472,679.45 
        </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Which looks like this:

```
Cash Activity               | Friday 05-JAN-18
______________________________________________
Prior Day Available Balance | $123,456.58
```

Is there anyway I can parse this in Powershell to an output XML looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Cash Activities>
    <Cash Activity>
        <Activity>Prior Day Available Balance</Activity>
        <Balance>123456.58</Balance>
    </Cash Activity>
</Cash Activities>
```

So far, the Powershell that I have only pulls it off of an E-mail, and saves it as an HTML file:

```
$account = "my.email@mycompany.com"
#date to append to new file name
$date = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd
$searchDate = Get-Date -Format M/dd/yyyy
Write-Host $searchDate
#file to save attachment as
$newFileName = "Balance_Import_$date.xml"
$newFilePath = "C:\MyDirectory\\"

#Go into Outlook and get the MAPI
$mail = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
$mailNS = $mail.GetNamespace("MAPI")


#get the account and Inbox we want
$myAcount = $mailNS.Folders | ? {$_.Name -eq $account}
$myInbox = $myAcount.Folders | ? {$_.Name -eq "Inbox"};
$myItems = $myAcount.Items | ? {$_.ReceivedTime.Date -eq $searchDate};

#loop through the Inbox and get any Attachments with the extension of .EXCEL
foreach ($f in $myInbox)
{
    foreach($i in $f.Items)
    {
        Write-Host "Checking "$i.Subject"..."

        if($i.ReceivedTime.Date -eq $searchDate)
        {
            Write-Host "---"
            Write-Host $i.Subject
            Write-Host "---"

            foreach($a in $i.Attachments)
            {
                if($a.FileName -like "*.EXCEL")
                {
                    #Move the attachment to the desired directory
                    $a.SaveAsFile((Join-Path $newFilePath $newFileName))
                    Write-Host $a.FileName " Saved as HTML"

                    #TODO: PARSE HTML INTO XML

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing the fake Excel / HTML input may have some issues:

1. HTML is not well-formed.
2. HTML Entities like `&nbsp;` will break the XML Parser.

Assuming your HTML example above takes care of the first issue, you can brute force the second issue by decoding the input like this:

```
[xml]$html = [System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode(@'
<table class="c41">
    <tr class="c5">
        <td valign="top" class="c6"><p class="c7"><span class="c8">Cash Activity </span> 
        </p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c9"><p class="c10"><br/><span class="c2">FRIDAY&nbsp;&nbsp; </span><br/><span class="c2"> </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c5">
        <td valign="top" class="c6"><p class="c11"><br/></p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c9"><p class="c10"><br/><span class="c2">05-JAN-18</span><br/><span class="c2"> </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="c12">
        <td valign="top" class="c13"><p class="c7"><span class="c14">Prior Day Available Balance</span></p>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" class="c15"><p class="c10"><span class="c16">6,472,679.45 
        </span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
'@);
```

Now it's just a matter of some simple XPath to select the nodes you want to get the desired XML you specified above (*tested and working)*:

```
$xml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Cash Activities>

'@;
$rows = $html.DocumentElement.SelectNodes('//tr');
foreach ($row in $rows) {
    if ($row.GetAttribute('class') -eq 'c12') {
        $xml += "`t<Cash Activity>`n";
        $spans = $row.SelectNodes('.//descendant::span[@class]');
        if ($spans.Count -eq 2) {
            $xml += "`t`t<Activity>$($spans[0].InnerText.Trim())</Activity>`n"; 
            $xml += "`t`t<Balance>$($spans[1].InnerText.Trim())</Balance>`n"; 
        }
        $xml += "`t</Cash Activity>`n";
    }
}

$xml += @'
</Cash Activities>
'@;
```

Comment: I will agree 100% the HTML isn't well-formed at all. I'm coming from C#, but is there a way to replace the `nbsp;` with a `""`" to make up for that?

Comment: @jDave1984 - It's already in my answer. The first block of code uses `[System.Net.WebUtility]::HtmlDecode` on the input HTML to deal with the `HTML Entities`.  Note _well-formed_ is a **separate** issue. (non closed tags, unquoted attributes, etc) Your HTML sample above is actually _well-formed_, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to get the code sample I wrote to work.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: @jDave1984 - :-)

Comment: You have no idea how much of a happy dance I'm doing. Our biggest issue was getting this HTML to somehow be ingested by SSIS and now this is totally easier to do so with

Answer (score 0):

Since there's such a thing as `ConvertTo-XML`, your question should be "How do I convert an HTML table into a Powershell object".

For tables where you don't know the elements, you can use regex even though it's bad practice. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/4fc6d20c-87bd-44e4-8e46-c72d63fe7b41/html-table-to-powershell-object?forum=ITCG

Once you get your data into a Powershell object, it should be really easy to change around the headers, or clean the data however you would like.

Then use the aforementioned cmdlet to convert to XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Internet Explorer COM object to get at the HTML structure then extract the data you want and finally generate the XML. Here's an example showing how you might do this:

```
# Create the IE com object
$oIE = New-Object -COM InternetExplorer.application

# Load the HTML document
$oie.Navigate("$pwd/html.htm")

# Function to convert the html COM object graph into PSCustomObjects
# This makes the tree a bit easier to work with since you can access by node name
function Export-Html  ($html)
{
    [pscustomobject] @{
        $html.NodeName = @{
            children = $html.Children | foreach { Export-Html $_ }
            text = $html.InnerText
        }
    }
}

# Convert the HTML into a PSCustomObject graph
$obj = Export-Html $oie.Document.Body

# Get the activity string explicitly walking the document hierarchy (could use tree search instead...)
$activity = $obj.BODY.children.
              Table.Children.
                Tbody.children.
                  TR[2].Children[0].
                   TD.
                     Text

# Get the balance, cast to double to get rid of the commas in the HTML text
[double] $balance = $obj.BODY.children.
                      Table.Children.
                        Tbody.children.
                          TR[2].Children[1].
                            TD.
                              Text

# Finally emit the XML with activity and balance substituted
@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Cash Activities>
    <Cash Activity>
        <Activity>$activity</Activity>
        <Balance>$balance</Balance>
    </Cash Activity>
</Cash Activities>
"@
```